# Make randomly positioned elements change position responsively within parent

Tags: html, jquery, css, parent-child, window-resize

new to stack overflow, so apologies if I'm missing something here.

Question 1: I've got this code that positions elements randomly within its parent - its woking great until I resize the screen. How would I do this responsively, so that the elements move within the parent container proportionally?

Question 2: Is there a way I could make sure that the dots don't overlap, and there's a specific amount of space between them - like padding / margins (the dots will all stay the same size if that helps). If I understand correctly this isn't possible with just CSS with my current setup.

All comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated!!

Here's my current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <style>
    *{
       box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
      
    .container{
       margin: auto;
       display: block;
       width:90VW;
       height:90VH;
       border:1px solid grey;
       position:relative;
    }

    .random{
       position:absolute;
       width:8px;
       height:8px;
       border-radius: 8px;
       background-color: antiquewhite;
       border: solid grey;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '.random' ).each(function() {
      $holder = $(this).parent();
      $divWidth  = $holder.width();
      $divHeight = $holder.height();
      $(this).css({
        'left': Math.floor( Math.random() * Number( $divWidth ) ),
        'top' : Math.floor( Math.random() * Number( $divHeight ) )
      });        
    })
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--- ↓ ↓ M A I N  C O N T E N T ↓ ↓ --->
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <a class="random" href="index.html"></a>
      <a class="random" href="index.html"></a>
      <a class="random" href="index.html"></a>
      <a class="random" href="index.html"></a>
      <a class="random" href="index.html"></a>
      <a class="random" href="index.html"></a>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-------------------------------------->
</body>
</html>
```